# Flask server redirects all connected clients to a page when some event occurs

Tags: python, flask, websocket, socket.io

I'm very new of Flask, JavaScript, HTML, etc. So, probably, this is a silly question.

I have a Flask server with one client connected. When this client pushes a button, the server sends a new page to it.
It's easy and I know how to do it.

Now, suppose there are more than one client connected to the server. Is it possible, and how, to send the new page to all the clients when one of them pushes that button?
I've tried with socketIO, I'm able to make the server traps the button click, and  send a text message back to all the clients, but this terminates my successes. I'm not able to make the page change on all the clients side.

When a client connects to 127.0.0.1:5000, the server renders index.html

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

this is the index.html

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="message">


    <button id="send">Send</button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
              integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js')}}"></script>
</body>
```

and this is the js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');

    $('#send').on('click', function() {
        var message = $('#message').val();

        socket.emit('message from user', message);
    });

    socket.on('from Flask', function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
    });
...
```

When the user clicks on the button, the server uppers the message sent by the client and broadcasts it to all the clients that are connected. Each client then shows it in a popup.

```
@socketio.on('message from user')
def receive_message_from_user(message):
    print ('USER MESSAGE {}'.format(message))
    emit ('from Flask', message.upper(), broadcast=True)
```

My intention is that, each client, instead of receiving this message from the server, goes to the a different page.

Comment: It is possible yes and it seems you are on the right course, take a look at this for excample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477572/listener-in-front-end-to-listen-on-back-end-listener . Here the typical setup is outlined, to be more precise you would have to display some code yourself.

Comment: Thank you Alexander. As you suggested, I've added some code

Comment: If you are still stuck, can you share a github link with the code so that I can take a look? Anyway, socket-io seems the way to go.

Comment: Thank you @miquelvir. This is the link: https://github.com/federicomnc/Flask-WebSocket
Now it works, but I still have a question that you can find in a comment in the app.py script

Comment: Answered!------

Answer (score 1):

I have reviewed the code. The 'from Flask' broadcast does work.

```
@socketio.on('message from user')
def receive_message_from_user(message):
    print ('USER MESSAGE {}'.format(message))
    emit('from Flask', message.upper(), broadcast=True)
    emit('redirect', {'url': url_for('home')}, broadcast=True)
```

(js)

```
socket.on('from Flask', function(msg) {
        alert("from flask: " + msg);
    });
```

The think that might have confused you is that it only works if you are not in the index page, this is because home is not importing the script.js. This will make the message appear (although you might want to have two different scripts, otherwise the redirect will also be activated when on the home page).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Home!!</h1>
 <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js')}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```